# Parses JSON from Web instantly but takes forever to load on app

Tags: flutter, dart

so I have an app where I want to print certain elements from a web API and I tried adding a "print" line just to make sure it is parsing what I want, and whenever I click the specifir button on the app (which links me to another page where the parsed text appears on the screen) it instantly prints on the console by takes forever to actually show the text on the screen... is there any obvious reason for this that I am just not seeing or something?

Anyways, thanks for any answer :)

If you want to see my code feel free to ask for it as I don´t mind sharing it!

Here is the class used to get and parse data from the api:

```
class CanteenInfo {
  final String canteenUrl = 'https://sigarra.up.pt/feup/pt/mob_eme_geral.cantinas';
  List plates = ["sopa", "carne", "peixe", "dieta", "vegetariano"];
  List canteenMenu = [];
  String workingHours = "yes";
  String date = "ini";

  CanteenInfo() {
    getWebsiteData();
  }

  Future getWebsiteData() async {
    var response =  await http.get(Uri.parse(canteenUrl));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      workingHours = data[3]["horario"];
      date = data[3]["ementas"][0]["data"];
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        canteenMenu.add(data[3]["ementas"][0]["pratos"][i]["descricao"]);
      }
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('Failed to read $canteenUrl');
    }
  }

  String getHours() {
    return workingHours;
  }
}
```

Here is the flutter/dart class used to display it on the app:

```
class WorkingHours extends StatefulWidget {
  const WorkingHours({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WorkingHours> createState() => _WorkingHours();
}

class _WorkingHours extends State<WorkingHours> {

  String hours = "yes";
  CanteenInfo canteen = CanteenInfo();

  Future getHours() async {
    setState(() {
      hours = canteen.workingHours;
    });
  }

  var flag = false;

  loadData()async{
    flag = true;
    canteen = CanteenInfo();
    await getHours();
    setState((){flag=false;});
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    getHours();

    if (hours == "yes" && !flag) {
      loadData();
    }
    if (flag) {
      return const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator()
          )
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text('EasyFood'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container (
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'Horário de Funcionamento',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
              ),
              const Text(
                  '(Segunda a sexta)',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                  )
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 100),
              Text(
                  'Lunch: ' + hours,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20
                  )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a bunch of reasons, none of which are obvious. Please share the code.

Comment: @Lasslos05 just editted the question for you to see it :)